# Can we have modified files and deleted files in the same workflow to upload content from GitHub to s3 bucket using GitHub actions

Tags: github, action

I have created separate workflows for the modified files and deleted files to upload content from github to s3 bucket using github actions .

is it possible to create one workflow for the modified and deleted files to upload from github to aws s3 bucket using github actions